# How to install flutter in the pre installed Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am trying to install Flutter in my existing android Studio. I was using it for android projects but now I want to learn flutter projects. I followed the steps given in this [video](https://youtu.be/hfz_AraTk_k) but now I am getting this as an error(All the sdk files are installed in D drive).

Should I move both of them to the same location?

```
C:\Users\prasa>flutter doctor
Checking Dart SDK version...
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine ...
Expanding downloaded archive...
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Downloading Material fonts...                                       3.2s
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                      210ms
Downloading package sky_engine...                                1,510ms
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...                            9.3s
Downloading flutter_patched_sdk_product tools...                    4.6s
Downloading windows-x64 tools...                                   38.2s
Downloading windows-x64/font-subset tools...                     1,767ms
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.978], locale en-IN)
[X] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

C:\Users\prasa>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed to resolve this.
```

How can I use same android studio for both Android(Koltin) and flutter projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The solution for me was opening Android Studio and going to SDK Manager, switch to the SDK Tools tab and check Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest).